# Add banner on Free shipping

Tags: shipping

I setup price based shipping fees calculation and they are reduced to zero when cart value is greater than 50 euros. Is it possible to show a code (maybe a banner) when shipping rates result is 0? I use lotusbreath one page checkout

Comment: Did you try Catalog Price Rules in Magento Backend

Comment: I don't think It can be do with Catalog Price Rules.
I need something like:
if shipping price is zero
then show <img src..... />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shipping Charge can get at checkout page  by below:

```
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
```

If you use magento default checkout onepage then just goto `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/onepage.phtml`.

Just put a condtion is if 
     `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
    ->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount()`  is `0` the put a banner.

**Like:**

```
<?php if(intval(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount())==0): ?>

// call banner
<?php endif; ?>
```